# NodeJS require module with path

Tags: node.js, npm

In the [`bluebird` node module](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird), there are two builds, the normal build, and the sync build.

The normal build, which is required by `require('bluebird')`, and the sync build, which is required by `require('bluebird/zalgo')`. How is that accomplished? It's a path, but for an nom package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you `npm install`, take a look in your `node_modules` directory.

You will see that under `bluebird` there is a `zalgo.js` which is the file used when doing `require('bluebird/zalgo')`.

That file has just one line

```
module.exports = require('./js/zalgo/bluebird.js');
```

and you can find these files under your `node_modules/bluebird` file tree also.

You can take a look at the node docs to find out exactly how node resolves the arguments to `require`.  Since your path does not start with `'.'` it will look in node_modules (or in the global location) and find `bluebird`.  Then it will resolve the rest of the path.

There is more to this, of course, and the docs will tell the full story, but this should get you started.